# xsd with c++-like templates

Tags: templates, xsd

I've got an xsd with:

```
Position.X
Position.Y
Position.Z
```

and

```
Velocity.X
Velocity.Y
Velocity.Z
```

and a ValueUnitPair containing:

```
Value
Unit
```

Is it possible to have something like:
TUnitPair[T] containing:

```
T
Unit
```

so I could use TUnitPair[Position] and TUnitPair[Velocity]